# What's the best way of allowing a file object to be saved and later retrieved and opened using FETCH

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a drag and drop UI that, on drop, gives me a File Object.

I'd like to save this on a database and later retrieve it and open it - it can be any file type.

I have an endpoint for my POST, but am struggling to understand how to go from  File object to DB and then GET for opening it again.

I'm not sure on what's the best approach to this - I've heard a few...

- Save the File object to the DB and retrieve it
- Append the File object to FormData(), save that and retrieve the multiparts
- Save a blob and retrieve then convert and open the URL for that.

All these different approaches all seem pretty wild. I just wondered if anyone out there has done anything like this before and give me any suggestions.

Comment: Which database? Why a file object? What kind of file? Why not some easily serialized-over-the-wire-and-stored format like JSON or XML that you convert to/from a file? I'm not going to say I've *never* done something like this, but it's very, very rare: like once in 10+ years of working on lots of different types of web application rare.

Comment: What backend (language, framework) are you using? What database?

Comment: As for designing a HTTP API for file upload and download, POST (with multipart-formdata) or direct PUT for upload and simple GET for download are the common approaches

Comment: Its a postgres db. 
The file can be a number of types -  .png, .doc, .txt etc..
A file object is returned by the drag and drop api and has this shape

{
lastModified: 1573555477610
lastModifiedDate: Tue Nov 12 2019 10:44:37 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}
name: "Capture.PNG"
size: 54603
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
}